# getting a declared method with reflection if the arg to that method is a class that isn't in the class path at compile time

Tags: java, reflection

```
Method _loadPlayer = PokeballManager.class.getDeclaredMethod(
        "loadPlayer", Class.class);// loadPlayer(EntityPlayerMP)
```

Where the method is loadPlayer(EntityPlayerMP),
EntityPlayerMP is dynamically remapped by the parent application and is not available in classpath at compile time,
How would i get the method for this without having the class available at compile time?

Comment: @Pshemo Why did you delete your comment? It seems like the only way.

Comment: @Pshemo No! Don't go! Post it as an answer. We'll follow up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like calling `Class.forName(fqn)` to get the `Class` object for `fqn`, then pass the resulting object as the 2nd argument of `getDeclaredMethod`.

(Assuming that `fqn` is the fully qualified classname for `EntityPlayerMP` represented as a `String`.)

---

However, it strikes me that it would be cleaner to create an statically compiled interface `EntityPlayerAPI` as the API for your dynamic `EntityPlayerMP` class (or classes).  Then redeclare the `loadPlayer` method as:

```
      PokeballManager.loadPlayer(EntityPlayerAPI)
```

This would allow you to get rid of at least some of the reflection here.